# cxGrid expand row height to new line with enter

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe4, tcxgrid

This is a little hard to explain so please bear with me. When I am editing a text field in one of the columns I would like to,when I hit enter, go to new line under the edited text so the grid basically expands. 
Options-View-CellAutoHeight set to true expands the cell but editing is terrible.Cant
see a thing where the first line is,where it ends,etc...

Here is the grid:

[image]

I can not go after the last letter 'a' with my mouse cursor and hit enter so another line gets added. Which settings regulate this ? I know it can be done since I had a grid once and could do this.

EDIT: This requires no code just applied settings.

Comment: You are aware that Developers Express has their own support forums, right?

Comment: If you assign "Properties" property of corresponding column to "Memo", then TcxMemo will be used for editing with all regular TMemo functionality. From short description without any code it is hard to understand what is wrong, i agree with Ken, you can ask DEX support, they answer quite fast usually. P.S. They also will ask for instructions and example of code to reproduce problem.

Comment: No,this is not done in  any code. Just apply some settings and that's all. Just cant remember which they were.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tested it with `DevExpress VCL 13.2` and it can be easily done without coding (if I understood what you want to achieve).

Basically, you need to set following properties:

- Assign a `Memo` to the `Properties` of your column and make sure its `WantReturns` property is set to true.
- In your `TableView` set the `OptionsView.CellAutoHeight` property to true.
- Also in your `TableView`, set the `OptionsBehavior.EditAutoHeight` to either `eahEditor` (editor is sized vertically to fit the content) or `eahRow` (the entire row is sized when editing) as needed.